# Am I considered hating Qur'an and kufr?

Tags: sin, kufr

my parents play Alquran audio recitation, and sometimes I don't like it when I want to enjoy playing video game or enjoy something (even the things that is haram) and I think the Qur'an recitation audio bothering it,am I considered hating Qur'an and kufr? I still listen to Quran when I'm not playing games/enjoy something or when I want, but how to stop think that the Qur'an audio is bothering me when I want to enjoy something? Please help

Answer (score 0):

This platform is actually not intended for getting personal advice but I don't want to leave you without an answer.

I suppose that you are a teenager, and for sure you are not the only teenager who likes gaming and doing things your parents don't. Gaming in general is makruh (disliked / not recommended), some games may be haram (there are a lot of articles about it on this platform), but it's not kufr.

Liking and doing things that are haram is a sin and you should avoid at least to do it.

In contrast, you are quite right not to like to hear Quran recitation all the time but only if you really listen and concentrate. This is a more respectful way to receive the Word than letting it play in the background while you are doing something else.

So, go your own way with God, keep His commandments and be careful with gaming - it's not the real world.